# Docker PHP MySQL connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli, docker-compose

I am trying to run a site using multiple container configuration - one for apache, second for mysql and third for myadmin. Everything starts fine, setup runs smooth but when I try to run a PHP application I get `mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in system/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysqli.php [54]` error.

It seems that there's something wrong with the connection settings but I checked the site through PHP MyAdmin running on separate container and copied the db host IP from there just to be sure. How can I/should I connect from PHP container to MySQL db?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./etc/php
      args:
         - APP_HOST=${APP_HOST}
         - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
         - MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:80
      - ${APP_PORT_SSL}:443
    volumes:
      - ./var/bin/:/tmp/bin/
      - ./app/:/var/www/html/
      - ./log/apache2/:/var/log/apache2/
      - ./etc/php/conf/:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
  db:
    build:
      context: ./etc/mysql
      args:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - DUMP_FILE=${DUMP_FILE}
    volumes:
      - ./etc/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf/conf.d
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./log/:/var/log/
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - ${MYADMIN_PORT}:80
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpmyadmin.localhost
```

And the `.env` with variables:

```
VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.local

APP_PORT=80
APP_PORT_SSL=443
MYADMIN_PORT=8081

APP_HOST=foo.local
ADMIN_APP_HOST=admin-foo.local

MYSQL_DATABASE=foo_local
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_HOST=172.26.0.2
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

Oh, and here's the code I try to run:

```
 $this->link = $socket ? new mysqli(null, $user, $pass, $database, $port, $socket) :
new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database, $port);
```

Output of `echo $host.'<br>'.$user.'<br>'.$pass.'<br>'.$database.'<br>'.$port.'<br>'.$socket;` is following:

```
172.26.0.2
root
root
hq_local
3306
```

Comment: Have you checked the IP address of the database container?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check your container IP with a `docker inspect [container name]` but write IP in a file is not very good. Replace IP by name of your db container.

Comment: OK. the IP was wrong. I copied it from `myadmin` panel... hoever container name is better idea indeed. Can I use the name from `docker-compose.yml` instead of the name given by `docker ps`?

Comment: Yes you can use the name from docker-compose.yml

Comment: this is the exact solution much needed i hope people reach here when they got stuck

Answer (score 9):

You can always use `host.docker.internal` as IP, therefore you can use something like this:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=host.docker.internal;port=3306;dbname=db', 'root', 'pass');
```

Comment: After 3 days of searching, this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the  `/etc/hosts` configuration inside your web service container for container linkage.

```
docker exec -it <container_name> cat /etc/hosts
```

Docker network won't be assigning the same IP to db container that you have specified for the MYSQL_HOST all the time. So better ti use the conatiner name in order to connect from web container.

Also, based on the context that you have specified in docker-compose.yml, try this:

```
new mysqli('etc/mysql', $user, $pass, $database, $port);
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to specify the value of the host in mysql the official environment variable is `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST:  localhost` if you do not do that then the host becomes the name of the service which in your case it is `db`.

Comment: Yes had this in docker compose file

`links: # for mysql container - db:db`

so just had to change the hostname to db

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in `.env` file and call the environment variables from there. Don´t worry about changing code if you write it as:

```
$mylink = mysqli_connect(
    env("DB_HOST"),
    env("DB_USER"),
    env("DB_PASS"),
    env("DB_NAME"),
    env("DB_PORT",3306)
)
```